# Ubuntu 20.04 laptop not charging

Tags: 20.04, battery

this is my first time posting and my first time using Linux/Ubuntu.
I recently installed Ubuntu as the OS on an Hp G3 820 and it worked completely fine for a couple of hours, but when i unplugged it to move it(while it was still on) it stopped charging. the AC adapter is detected but it gets "not charging" from the top right menu. checked the power statistics app and it shows (when plugged in"
AC adapter - "Device - line_power_AC" Type - "AC adapter" Supply - "yes" Refreshed - "0 seconds" Online - "Yes"
Laptop battery - State - "Waiting to charge"
Supply is white and battery is green. i have also tried another charger and to reset the power by shutting it off and holding in the power button for 30 seconds. when i then boot up the machine it charges for a couple seconds before going back to not charging. sorry if this is lacking in information or incoherent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out. It doesnt charge when above a certain percentage to protect the battery. Sorry for the query!